# Online deseasonalization of time series data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, seasonality, online-algorithms

Are there any existing methodologies of deseasonalizing time series data online, in order to avoid lookahead bias? It seems that if you don't deaseasonalize time series data online, you would not be able to evaluate a machine learning algorithm that runs online on time series data that you wish to deseasonalize.

Comment: Seasonal factors can be auto-projective (AR or MA) , deterministic or a suitable combination of both. Deterministic seasonal factors like a January effect may have occurred each January for every year in our data OR there may have been no January effect for the first half of your data but one for the last half . Are these the kinds of effects that you wish to pull out of your data which may have many levels and/or many time trends and/or many pulses with possible break points in error variance or parameters over time ? Where would you want such a resource to be located . This resource already